# how to create new column in pandas dataframe by indexing desirable parts of other columns

Tags: python, pandas

this is what i have:

```
fertility_rate =[3.97,3.68,3.14,2.73,2.27,2.02,1.86,1.70,1.68,1.32,1.31, 1.31,1.39,1.45,1.50,1.55,1.59]
year = ['1950-1955','1955-1960','1960-1965','1965-1970','1970-1975','1975-1980','1980-1985','1985-1990','1990-1995','1995-2000','2000-2005','2005-2010','2010-2015','2015-2020','2020-2025','2025-2030','2030-2035']
fertility = pd.DataFrame({'year': year, 'fertility': fertility_rate})
fertility.set_index('year', inplace=True)


fertility['fertility_high']=fertility['fertility'] +0.5
```

This code makes new column  by adding 0.5 to every row in the column.
My goal is to for first 12 rows ( from 1955 to 2015 year) to copy values from a first column (fertility), and for 12+ rows to add 0.5.

Comment: Use `.iloc[]` to index into both the rows and columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you need same value as fertility in fertility high for the first 12 rows and increment by 0.5 for the rest

```
fertility['fertility_high']=fertility['fertility'].copy() 

fertility.iloc[12:, 1]+=0.5 

    fertility   fertility_high
year        
1950-1955   3.97    3.97
1955-1960   3.68    3.68
1960-1965   3.14    3.14
1965-1970   2.73    2.73
1970-1975   2.27    2.27
1975-1980   2.02    2.02
1980-1985   1.86    1.86
1985-1990   1.70    1.70
1990-1995   1.68    1.68
1995-2000   1.32    1.32
2000-2005   1.31    1.31
2005-2010   1.31    1.31
2010-2015   1.39    1.89
2015-2020   1.45    1.95
2020-2025   1.50    2.00
2025-2030   1.55    2.05
2030-2035   1.59    2.09
```

Comment: @waltexwq, great that it works. Do remember to upvote/accept the answer if it answers your query fully